# What does 'ZScaleInterval()' do in AstroPy?

Tags: image-processing, astropy, astronomy, fits

I have looked at the documentation but I didn't find what I was looking for. All the explanations I could find on the web states that this is used to improve contrasts in images. 
Look at this code for example(that is made to run on an astronomical FITS Image):

```
from astropy.visualization import ZScaleInterval
z = ZScaleInterval()
z1,z2 = z.get_limits(image_data)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image_data, vmin=z1, vmax=z2)
```

According to the documentation, `get_limits` returns the minimum and maximum value in the interval based on the values provided. I'm guessing it means the maximum and minimum intensities. What do `vmax` and `vmin` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ZScaleInterval()`:

AstroPy's `ZScaleInterval()` is actually an implementation of IRAF's ZScale Algorithm. According to the IRAF's documentation, the algorithm was designed to display the image values near the median image value without the time-consuming process of computing a full image histogram. This was very useful in the earlier days when computing power was still an issue for very big `.fits` files.
AstroPy implemented the interval to give the ability to compare their plots with plots generated using IRAF. Also, it's just a very brilliant algorithm and gives you the almost right `vmin` and `vmax` value required for your specific task.

What do `vmin` and `vmax` does:

Your `image_data` is basically a 2D array with each element representing some value, let's say brightness. When you plot `image_data` using `plt.imshow()`, you basically plot these brightness values stored at a specific point in that 2D array. `plt.hist(image_data.ravel())` will give you a histogram of the flattened image array, which will show mainly two peaks (assuming there is a single galaxy in the image), one for the sky background and one for the galaxy itself.
To clearly see faint objects in your image, you improve contrast by setting `vmin` and `vmax` to the sides of the intensity peak of the galaxy.
Now, generating this histogram for big images can be very computationally expensive, and that's where `ZScaleInterval()` interval comes in handy.

You can find more details here: https://js9.si.edu/js9/plugins/help/scalecontrols.html

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding `vmin` and `vmax` are the lower and upper limits of the gray values in your image.